# fs.readFileSync doesn't wait

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
fs.readFileSync(process.env.id_to_name, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    /*
    a lot of stuff
    */

    fs.mkdirSync(`clips`);
    fs.writeFileSync(`clips/recap.json`, '{"players":[]}', 'utf8');
});

fs.readFileSync(`clips/recap.json`, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    var info = JSON.parse(data);
    info.players.push(/* stuff */);
    fs.writeFileSync(`clips/recap.json`, JSON.stringify(info), 'utf8', function (err) { });
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.
The second fs.readFileSync just doesn't wait for the first one to end so it doesn't find the file he should read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `fs.readFileSync()` incorrectly.  It does not accept a callback as an argument and does not call a callback.  See doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options).

I don't know if you meant to show us `fs.readFile()` that does accept a callback or not.

`fs.readFileSync()` returns its result directly (in a synchronous fashion) from the function call as in:

```
 let data = fs.readFileSync(someFileName, someEncoding);
```

It does not use a callback and it throws an exception if there's an error reading the file.

---

If you meant to show us an example using `fs.readFile()`, then it's a non-blocking, asynchronous call.  If you want your second file read to wait until the first one is done, you would have to put the second file read INSIDE the completion callback of the first.

Also, please never write code like `if (err) throw err;` inside an asynchronous callback.  That's a pointless piece of code that does nothing useful as nothing can catch that throw and you have no way to communicate back errors.  It is most unfortunate that nodejs documentation shows that regularly in its examples as real world code should never do that.  You will need to write real error handling where you either handle the error in some way and continue or you abort the process or you communicate back the error (probably with a callback) so the calling code can handle and see the error.  Exceptions throw in asynchronous callbacks do NOT propagate back to the caller.  They end up going back to the bowels of the file system code where the callback was triggered from where you cannot catch or handle them.

---

If you really mean to be using all synchronous calls, then you would write your code like this:

```
try {
    let data1 = fs.readFileSync(process.env.id_to_name, 'utf-8');

    // other code here

    fs.mkdirSync(`clips`);
    fs.writeFileSync(`clips/recap.json`, '{"players":[]}', 'utf8');
    
    let data2 = fs.readFileSync(`clips/recap.json`, 'utf-8');
    var info = JSON.parse(data2);
    info.players.push(/* stuff */);
    fs.writeFileSync(`clips/recap.json`, JSON.stringify(info));
    
} catch(err) {
    // handle errors here
    console.log(err);
}
```

Note that this code can likely only be run once without error because `fs.mkdirSync('clips')` will fail unless you set the `recursive` flag.

Hint, you can use `require()` to load and parse a JSON file in one step so you don't have to read it and then parse it into a Javascript object.